# Codeigneter : How to use Order by in Active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a database column `"days"`. I would like to insert the days of the week randomly example `Tuesday,Monday,Thursday,Wednesday`

```
| id | Days
-------------------
| 1  | Tuesday
| 2  | Monday
| 3  | Thursday
| 4  | Wednesday
```

How would I return the days in order to my view using Codeigniter Active Record ?

Comment: ~in order in my view ~ means what you want to get data based in days or something else

Comment: i would like to get the data based on days in order ie Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday

Comment: From your query did you try using CASE syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column **Days** only contains the day of week, then you could do this:

```
$this->db->query(SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY FIELD(Days, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY'));
```

Comment: this has failed

Comment: Sorry it has worked just fine, i misspelled. Thank you @Tiger